# Upgraded to 12.04, can't login because home directory disappeared

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, mount, login, home-directory

I have just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, and at my first login, I typed in my password, and then a quick console screen showed that some `mountall` event failed.

Indeed, I had some networked filesystems with mounting point `/home/here` that seemed to no longer exist, creating the problem. So the screen shortly turns black and the system gets back to the login screen, playing the drum sound.

Alternatively, when I log in from e.g. tty1, I have a `No directory, logging in in with HOME=/` message.

Did I just loose all my data? Is there a way to get back to my home and data?!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I reckon is to boot up from a Live CD and rescue your data to a USB drive or portable hard disc before you start playing around. Do you store your files and data on the same partition as the OS??